# Error: Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am getting the following error on production server. It works well on localhost.

> Error: Sequence contains more than one element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is an `InvalidOperationException` thrown by the [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) method.

This method is supposed to return only one element, and your query is returning more than one, you have to check the criteria you use on your query.

It will also throw an exception if it doesn't find an element.  You can use `SingleOrDefault()` method to return null (or default value, i.e. 0 for int) if there are no records.

If you are expecting multiple elements but just one the first one, you can use `First` instead of `Single` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the data is different, and that's why with the same criteria you are getting the error only on production. I would recommend you to get a copy of the production database and check that query, try to debug and put a `Where` instead the `Single` so you will be able to see what are the rows that shouldn't be there.